# How to remove duplicates from a list whilst preserving order?

Tags: python, list

If I have a list like this:
`lst = ['a','a','b','a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c','d','e','a', 'b', 'b', 'b']`,

when I am apply set(lst), it will remove all the duplicates. But I only wanna remove the consistently duplicates and keep the rest of then in order, so my ideal output is `['a', 'b','a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a', 'b']`

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Shorthand version of groupby solution: `[*next(zip(*groupby(lst)))]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import groupby

lst = ['a','a','b','a', 'a', 'c', 'c', 'c','d','e','a', 'b', 'b', 'b']

print([key for key, _ in groupby(lst)])
```